# Value in cell to determine reference to another workbook

Tags: excel, function

I am attempting to build an efficient way to create a function that can reference a column in workbook 1 to get a cell's value from workbook 2. In column A I have a formula that gives the column number I want to use in my function for column D and column B has the column number converted to the letter. (I have both A & B but if I can accomplish with just column A I would delete column B)

Ex A3=3 B3=C and I would like D3 to equal 'workbook 2'C5. I have tried using ADDRESS and can get C$5$, but I don't know how to get this to give the value of C5 from workbook 2, is there a more efficient way to get value of C5 of workbook 2? (row 5 is not important just an example number).

I'm not sure if this means using ADDRESS or another function, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Almost done. What you need is `indirect()`. When `b3` is `=ADDRESS(5,A3)` which is `$C$5`, put `=INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&B3)` in `d3`.